# WiFi connection lags from time to time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, sniffing, lag, peer-to-peer

My home LAN connection lags from time to time (approx once a minute).

This is noticeable by temporary pauses of continuos operations like file copying, RDP working and video playback with small buffer.

Logically connection does not break.

It looks like it performs some reconnection or service operation periodically on low wifi level.

How to catch what is happening?

No correspondent errors found in the Windows Event Viewer.

**UPDATE**

I found some effect possible correlating with lags: approximately each 1 second my router is reporting about blocked attempts of external connections. Each time it is a bunch of 10-15 attempts from different IP addresses and ports.

Each bunch possibly coincides with WiFi lag, but I am not sure.

Wired network stays ok all the time although.

I think that this connections are beacuse of my usage of Torrent client. It is possible that other clients rememebered my host and trying to connect it from time to time. Other reason is remembering in DHT network, which is also included in Torrent program I use.

Hence the addendum question is how to exclude myself from DHT and or Torrent network? May be it is enough to keep down for a while?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give more information about the setup. What kind of Wi-Fi, what is connected to it. Is it single channel or dual channel, do you have both n and a/b/g and do you have a mix of devices connected?

You might well be getting interference from either another Wi-Fi network nearby or from a device such as a fridge or microwave, DECT phones or even wireless doorbells!

You should use a Wi-Fi scanner application on a PC to see if you have nearby networks on the same channel as yours.

Or it could just be that your Wi-Fi router is dying, I've had this happen on a couple of home routers. Though the biggest problem I used to have is the sheer number of Wi-Fi networks close by (too many students!). I upgraded to a more powerful router and added an Edimax Wi-Fi device that can act as its own access point or as an extender or booster. Now I don't have any problems ;)

Comment: I need recommendations about how to solve the problem myself: loggers, even viewers, sniffers and so on.

Comment: Well, start with a Wi-Fi scanner on your PC as suggested.

Comment: Okay it was probably due to Bluetooth bugs on this notebook. Waiting statistical proof (creators of BT should be executed with extreme violence :) )